# RecordStore or PersistentStore to save data on blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, persistent-storage, recordstore

What is the best solution for saving data for Blackberry application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RMS API, size of single RecordStore is limited to 64Kb for 4.5 and before and 512kb for 4.6 and later.
If you use Persistent API, storage size is limited only by capacity of device - exactly as you described.

Persistent API is more powerful but requires code signing. MIDP doesn't required.

For more info look at following links.,

[Persistent Data Storage](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/184144-persistent-data-storage.html)

[Blackberry Data Storage](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/data_storage-summary.html)

[Persistent Storage Performance](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2007/10/30/persistent-storage-on-blackberry-curve-8300/)

Answer (score 1):

`PersistentStore` is more recommended to use when storing data on the device. Check the `RuntimeStore` too which is good to use too.